# sp_who2 BlkBy Sleeping Process Awaiting Command

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sp-who2

When running sp_who2, it appears one of my SQL commands is blocking but waiting on a process that is "Sleeping" and "Awaiting Command". This doesn't make any sense.

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing this? I know the DELETE is running inside a transaction that previously inserted a lot of rows into the table, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably have an open transaction on SPID 98. A blocking SPID does not have to be active

Try this, look at the [open_tran](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) column

```
SELECT
    p1.SPID AS blockedSPID, p2.SPID AS blockingSPID, ...
FROM 
    master..sysprocesses p1
    JOIN
    master..sysprocesses p2 ON p1.blocked = p2.spid
```

Following on, [this script gives](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Script-open-transactions-with-text-and-plans.aspx) you open transactions, last SQL and plan.

And have a read of [KB 224453](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453) for good measure

Comment: This was an issue with SSRS not reusing the connection that I opened the transaction with (thus never closing it), which ultimately meant that there was an open transaction holding down a lock on the table. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the SQLs you are running it would be extremely difficult to say. But based on the Delete/Insert scenario, is it not possible that you have started a transaction for insert and then you have opened another transaction to delete some of those inserted records without comminting previous transaction?

I have seen this kind of issue before and this is how it manifests itself.